# Pushing only uniqure elements in an array javscript

Tags: javascript

JSON DATA:

```
{
    "img": "83.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "83-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "dasfsdf",
    "lastName": "asdfasdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics II",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "84.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "84-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "sdfasdfae",
    "lastName": "asdfsdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "85.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "85-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "Kelly",
    "lastName": "Zsadfsdfo",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "86.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "86-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfia",
    "lastName": "Klasdfasdfa",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "87.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "87-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfst",
    "lastName": "asdfasdfantoro",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
```

LOOP

```
$.getJSON("gallery2.json", function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
    if (filters.Of(trimCategory(val.class)) === -1) {
      filters.push([val.class, trimCategory(val.class)]);
    }
  });
});
```

Expected Output

```
["Art I", "arti"],["H Ceramics II", "hceramicsii"],
["H Ceramics I", "hceramicsi"]
```

I am trying to loop through JSON Data and push the class name, along with a trimmed class which is renamed to the category to a new array. The actual output is listing all duplicates of each class.

Comment: Why are you using `filters.Of()` to test if the class is already in the array? That's not even close to what that method does. It's also `of`, not `Of`.

Answer (score 1):

Complexity consideration, if you want to do this in complexity O(n) you have to use an object (a hash map), if you try to find an object in an array you will end having an O(n^2). That's why my used the object r.

```js
const data = [{
    "img": "83.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "83-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "dasfsdf",
    "lastName": "asdfasdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics II",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "84.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "84-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "sdfasdfae",
    "lastName": "asdfsdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "85.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "85-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "Kelly",
    "lastName": "Zsadfsdfo",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "86.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "86-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfia",
    "lastName": "Klasdfasdfa",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "87.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "87-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfst",
    "lastName": "asdfasdfantoro",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
}]

function process(data){
  const r = {}
  for(const item of data){
    
    const key = item['class'].replace(/\s+/mg, '').toLowerCase()
    r[key] = [item['class'], key]
  }
  return Object.values(r).sort()
}

console.log(process(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing whether the class is already in the `filters` array correctly. Use `find()` with a function that checks the second element of each item.

```
$.getJSON("gallery2.json", function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    if (!filters.find(([_, trimmed]) => trimmed == trimCategory(val.class))) {
      filters.push([val.class, trimCategory(val.class)]);
    }
  });
});
```

```js
const data = [{
    "img": "83.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "83-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "dasfsdf",
    "lastName": "asdfasdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics II",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "84.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "84-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "sdfasdfae",
    "lastName": "asdfsdf",
    "class": "H Ceramics I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "85.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "85-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "Kelly",
    "lastName": "Zsadfsdfo",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "86.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "86-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfia",
    "lastName": "Klasdfasdfa",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "87.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "87-thumb.jpg",
    "firstName": "asdfasdfst",
    "lastName": "asdfasdfantoro",
    "class": "Art I",
    "title": ""
  }
];

let filters = [];

function trimCategory(cat) {
  return cat.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase();
}

$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  if (!filters.find(([_, trimmed]) => trimmed == trimCategory(val.class))) {
    filters.push([val.class, trimCategory(val.class)]);
  }
});

console.log(filters);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: script.js:88 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
style.css:1

Comment: `class` is a reserved word, I had to rename the variable.